# Bogus, AutoFixture, others(?): How to fill a nested model with fake data and set rules for specific properties?

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, autofixture, bogus

I have a very nested model that I want to create thousands of with fake data. But, also, some properties in the model need to be in a specific range or have specific rules. I looked at these two fake data generators:

**AutoFixture** only seems to generate fake data for everything.

**Bogus** can set rules like ranges for properties but all other properties remain null - or you have to define rules for all of them.

Did I miss something or is it not possible to fill the models with fake data and only set rules for specific properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoFixture enables you to establish rules for properties, either in a property-by-property basis, or by convention.

## Customise a specific property

You can use `Customize` to change the behaviour for a particular type, including properties:

```
[Fact]
public void CustomizeSpecificProperty()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.With(mo => mo.Number, 42));

    var actual = fixture.Create<MyClass>();

    Assert.Equal(42, actual.Number);
}
```

This particular customization changes the rule for all `MyClass.Number` properties; the value will always be exactly 42.

## Customize by convention

You can also match various properties by convention, often by looking at a combination of property type and name:

```
[Fact]
public void CustomizeTextPropertyByConvention()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new TextPropertyBuilder());

    var actual = fixture.Create<MyClass>();

    Assert.Equal("Foo", actual.Text);
}
```

This option also requires that you write a custom `TextPropertyBuilder` class:

```
public class TextPropertyBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi == null || pi.Name != "Text" || pi.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            return new NoSpecimen();

        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

This rule will apply to all `string` properties called `"Text"`, no matter on which class they're defined.

AutoFixture comes with a rich API that will enable you express many of such rules in a more succinct manner, but these are the main building blocks.

---

Both the above examples use this `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using `fixture.Create<MyClass>();` in the first example, will all other properties in the class also have contents?

Comment: @Thypari Yes https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#complex-type

Answer (score 17):

[**Bogus**](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) has a community extension called [**AutoBogus**](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus) written by **Nick Dodd** that lets you auto-generate rules for your models.

You can also override auto-generated rules that **AutoBogus** created with specific values for specific tests. Check out the [**AutoBogus**](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus) readme for more info.

Also, you don't have to choose one or the other. You can use both. **Bogus** has a `Faker` class  (not `Faker<T>`) that you can use without a fluent setup and without having to define a model `T`. The `Faker` class gives you access to all the datasets for realistic data generation. So, you can use **Bogus**' `Faker` object in combination with **AutoFixture**'s conventions. :)

Hope that helps!
Brian